Attribute error with LBHPFaceRecognizer and cv2.face
I am trying to initiate the LBHPFaceRecognizer, but the problem is every time I use cv2.face, it always gives me an Attribute error. Not just for the LBHPFaceRecognizer. I tried initiating it with  a function by adding brackets, tried createLBHPFaceRecognizer, tried LBHPFaceRecognizer_create(), nothing worked. Also, 'LBHPFaceRecognizer" is what pops up as an option after I type in cv2.face. I provided the code below, it is on the last few lines and below the code is my pip list. I tried downgrading opencv-contrib-python, it didn't work
import cv2
import cv2.face
import os

def generate_dataset():
    face_classifier = cv2.CascadeClassifier("C:/Users/Abdallah/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python312/Lib/site-packages/cv2/data/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml")
    
    def face_cropped(img):
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        faces = face_classifier.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
        # scaling factor=1.3
        # Minimum neighbor = 5
        if len(faces) == 0:
            return None
        for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
            cropped_face = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]
            return cropped_face
    
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    
    id = 1
    img_id = 0
    
    while True:
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if ret:
            if face_cropped(frame) is not None:
                img_id += 1
                face = cv2.resize(face_cropped(frame), (200, 200))
                face = cv2.cvtColor(face, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
                file_name_path = "C:/Users/Abdallah/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python312/Lib/site-packages/cv2/data/data/user." + str(id) + "." + str(img_id) + ".jpg"
                cv2.imwrite(file_name_path, face)
                cv2.putText(face, str(img_id), (50, 50), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 1, (0, 255, 0), 2)
                #(50,50) is the origin point from where text is to be written
                #font scale=1
                #thickness=2
                cv2.imshow("Cropped face", face)
                if cv2.waitKey(1) == 13 or int(img_id) == 200:
                    break
            else:
                print("No face detected")
        else:
            print("Error: Failed to read frame from the camera")
    
    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    print("Collecting samples is completed......")

#generate_dataset()

from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

def train_classifier(data_dir):
    path = [os.path.join(data_dir, f) for f in os.listdir(data_dir)]
    faces = []
    ids = []
    for image in path:
        img = Image.open(image).convert('L')
        imageNp = np.array(img, 'uint8')
        id = int(os.path.split(image)[1].split(".")[1])

        faces.append(imageNp)
        ids.append(id)
    ids = np.array(ids)

    clf = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer
    clf.train(faces, ids)
    clf.write("classifier.xml")

train_classifier("C:/Users/Abdallah/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python312/Lib/site-packages/cv2/data/data")

absl-py                 2.1.0
astunparse              1.6.3
certifi                 2024.2.2
charset-normalizer      3.3.2
colorama                0.4.6
contourpy               1.2.0
cycler                  0.12.1
engineering-notation    0.10.0
filelock                3.13.4
flatbuffers             24.3.25
fonttools               4.50.0
fsspec                  2024.3.1
gast                    0.5.4
google-pasta            0.2.0
grpcio                  1.62.2
h5py                    3.11.0
huggingface-hub         0.22.2
idna                    3.7
joblib                  1.3.2
keras                   3.3.2
kiwisolver              1.4.5
libclang                18.1.1
Markdown                3.6
markdown-it-py          3.0.0
MarkupSafe              2.1.5
matplotlib              3.8.3
mdurl                   0.1.2
ml-dtypes               0.3.2
namex                   0.0.8
numpy                   1.26.4
opencv-contrib-python   4.9.0.80
opencv-python           4.9.0.80
opt-einsum              3.3.0
optree                  0.11.0
packaging               24.0
pandas                  2.2.1
pillow                  10.2.0
pip                     24.0
protobuf                4.25.3
Pygments                2.17.2
pyparsing               3.1.2
python-dateutil         2.9.0.post0
pytz                    2024.1
tensorflow-intel        2.16.1
termcolor               2.4.0
threadpoolctl           3.4.0
tk-tools                0.16.0
tokenizers              0.19.1
tqdm                    4.66.2
transformers            4.40.1
typing_extensions       4.11.0
tzdata                  2024.1
urllib3                 2.2.1
Werkzeug                3.0.2
wheel                   0.43.0
wrapt                   1.16.0



Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\\Users\\Abdallah\\Downloads\\Code Linear Regression-20240324\\deep.py", line 68, in \<module\>
train_classifier("C:/Users/Abdallah/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python312/Lib/site-packages/cv2/data/data")
File "C:\\Users\\Abdallah\\Downloads\\Code Linear Regression-20240324\\deep.py", line 65, in train_classifier
clf = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: module 'cv2.face' has no attribute 'LBPHFaceRecognizer'

Process finished with exit code 1`


Hi there. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for more information about how to ask good questions.
